# On IOS10 , playing a wav file using https gives Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load, safari

Tags: javascript, safari, wav, mediaelement, ios10

On IOS10 beta, safari browser, when we try to play a wav file from a source which is https then
the player does not play the file. instead gives below error "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load""